# Create a function that wraps an alias, but prints out the alias string

Tags: ubuntu, bash, bashrc

I want to create a bash function that will basically wrap an alias, except that it will output what the alias is doing so I don't forget the actual command.

e.g.:

```
alias abc='cd ~/root'
```

So when I run it:

```
>abc
'you typed: cd ~/root'
/root>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want, but here's a function that wraps the creation of an alias that reminds you what it does:

```
$ reminderalias() {
> alias $1="echo 'You typed: $2'; $2"
> }
$ reminderalias abc 'cd ~/root'
$ abc
You typed: cd ~/root
$ #CWD is now ~/root
```

Note that this will have trouble with aliases containing certain special characters (mainly single-quotes as far as I can see).